# PostgreSQL cast float value to see it with thousands separator

Tags: postgresql, formatting

I'm doing the following query on a PostgreSQL table:

```
select precio::money,
       area
from table
```

The result looks like this:

```
price               area
$6.00               6200000000
$1,300,000,000.00   4800000000
$600,000,000.00     3003514620
$585,000,000.00      585000000
```

I'd like to format the `area` column (float type) to have the separators of thousands for readability, in a similar way I did for the `price` column.

Any suggestion with that?

Comment: Use `to_char()` to format the value

Comment: to_char(area) raise this error: ERROR: function to_char(character) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: `price` column is `numeric`, `area` column is `real` type, so I'm not storing the values as `character` as you said. The purpose of this formatting is only to visualize the information. Also. the database is running on a Cloud provider so the € problem won't exist.

Comment: Nop: select column_name,data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table_name' give me `area` as `real` type

Comment: If `area` is indeed `float` it should work: `select to_char(6200000000::float, '999G999G999G999');  6,200,000,000` Also the monetary setting can be changed by the client, so cloud hosting really does not apply.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I posted your answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
select precio::money,
       to_char(area, '9G999G999G999')
from table
```